# ts build sometimes fails to build ts modules correctly

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have a project with some typescript in it. Sometimes, the typescript doesn't build correctly; it uses the wrong module system, assigning exported members to a some export object rather than using require.js' `define`.

To get it to re-build, I jiggle the TS build tab of the projects settings, and the correct build rolls out.

What can be causing this? My guess is that the `csproj` file controls the build, though I don't know exactly how.

The typescript related entries in my `csproj` are

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>True</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptOutFile />
    <TypeScriptOutDir />
    <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
    <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptMapRoot />
    <TypeScriptSourceRoot />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />
```

How can I control the ts build in another way than clicking buttons and checking boxes in the settings tab, and what should I specifically change to get my build to always generate AMD-style modules?

Comment: I've been getting similar issues when the source was compiled-on-save. Unticking that and manually building (Ctrl+Shift+B) produces usable code consistently.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're changing your build configuration into release mode, not the Debug mode this is set for? Or you've got some other tool around that's trying to compile your TypeScript, and isn't following Visual Studio's project files convention, and instead defaulting to standard settings?

I would be tempted to try moving your config into a tsconfig.json file, and removing it from your Visual Studio project settings. That should make it pretty unambiguous (with the .json it will always be set regardless of your build settings, and will always understood by any tool that compiles TS), and as a nice side-effect makes it independent of Visual Studio too.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig.json.html has a guide on the format. I'd expect it to probably just be a matter of taking the existing settings above and directly transcribing them to JSON.

To get the specific AMD modules behaviour you're looking for, you just need to make sure you include `'module': 'amd'` inside the `compilerOptions` object of your JSON.

Comment: Thank you. I like the json config for the ts build a lot more, but I've been reluctant to try and go that way because of the "magic" I suspect the MSBuild build task performs in the way of ts references (being able to typecheck/autodiscover depedencies that shouldn't typecheck nor be autodiscovered), and the intellisense that I sort of expect depend on the project build task. It's the darndest thing to find documentation on. I'll give it a swing though.